# What is exactly Alfred referring to in this dialogue during conversation with Bruce?

Tags: dialogue, reference, dc-extended-universe, justice-league

In *Justice League*, when Bruce and Alfred were discussing over finding metahumans, they have the following conversation.

> **Alfred:** Victor Stone. Genius IQ, football scholarship to GCU, and deceased.
>
> **Bruce:** Figures. Fairy tales and ghost stories.
>
> **Alfred:** *One misses the days when one's biggest concerns were exploding wind-up penguins.*

In this last line, which event or thing is Alfred referring to?

Comment: i mean.... the "penguin" bit didn't give it away?

Comment: I didn't read the comics and watch old Batman movies, so I wouldn't have guessed it. I only watched Nolan's TDK trilogy and DCEU movies. I only know villains shown in those movies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That was a reference to famous Batman villain [Penguin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penguin_(character)). He is prominent character in many Batman related adaptations and most relatable I can think of is [*Batman Returns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Returns) where the main villain [Penguin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penguin_(character)) used army of penguins to bomb the city.

Comment: While you're right that it's clearly a reference to the Penguin, the army of penguins from *Batman Returns* were not wind-up.

Comment: @phantom42 but they were irritating and were there to explode the city

Comment: I'd agree that it doesn't necessarily have to be a reference to that specific incarnation of the Penguin rather than just a general one about Batman's ealier days. The wind-up penguin thing is a rather classic Penguin theme, I'd say.

Comment: This answer is disputed ([elsewhere](https://moviechat.org/tt0974015/Justice-League/5a56145237c1120014bb0288/exploding-wind-up-penguins-is-NOT-a-Batman-Returns-reference)).

Comment: I edited it a bit

Answer (score 3):

[LEGO Batman:  The Videogame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Batman:_The_Videogame) has Penguin using seemingly mechanical penguin bombs.  Demonstrated starting around 5:32 in [this video](https://youtu.be/ZyZmvXDtuQ8?t=5m32s).  (This is a player-controlled Penguin deploying the penguins.)

The 1988 Amiga game, [*Batman:  The Caped Crusader*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Caped_Crusader) had wind-up penguins.  I recall them having [flip-top heads hiding knee-high guns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdCuVrQofN8), but I do not recall them exploding.

Comment: Oh! LEGO Batman Movie, the best batman movie I've ever watched. Pure awesomeness.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir : There may be penguin bombs in the movie -- I haven't checked -- but I am referencing the console video game by Traveller's Tales, published by Warner Bros. Interactive in 2008.

Comment: Actually, what makes Lego Batman Movie so cool is that it mentions all the villains (penguin and tons of others, including the exploding wind-up penguins) and references all the batman incarnations since the 60s. (It even mentions Iron Man hahaha). That movie is a piece of art.